# Let $x_n=\frac{n+1}{n}\sin \frac{\pi n}{2}$, $n=1,2,3....$

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series

Let  $x_n=\frac{n+1}{n}\sin \frac{\pi n}{2}$, $n=1,2,3....$

find

(a). Inf$\{x_n:n=1,2,....\}$ and Sup$\{x_n:n=1,2,....\}$

(b)$\liminf_{n\to \infty} x_n $  and  $\limsup_{n\to \infty} x_n$

*My Idea:*

since given sequence $x_n=\frac{n+1}{n}\sin \frac{\pi n}{2}$=$2, 0, -4/3,0,5/4...$

so,Inf$\{x_n:n=1,2,....\}=0$

sup$\{x_n:n=1,2,....\}=2$ is i am correct...if so can help with question (b)

Comment: Note that $\sin \frac{\pi 2k}{2}=0$ and $\sin \frac{\pi (2k+1)}{2}=(-1)^k$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note that $\sin\frac{n\pi}2=0$ for even $n$ and 
$$
\sin\frac{n\pi}2=\begin{cases}
1,&n\equiv 1\bmod4\\
-1,&n\equiv 3\bmod4.
\end{cases}
$$
Hence for $n\geqslant 1$ we have
\begin{align}
x_{3n-2} &= 1+\frac1n\\
x_{3n-1} &= 0\\
x_{3n} &= -\left(1+\frac1n\right)\\
x_{3n+1} &= 0.
\end{align}
Since $n\mapsto 1+\frac1n$ is decreasing, it follows that $$\sup_n x_n=x_1 = 2$$ and $$\inf_n x_n = x_3 = -\frac43.$$ From $\lim_{n\to\infty}1+\frac1n = 1$ we see that
$$
\limsup_{n\to\infty} x_n = 1
$$
and
$$
\liminf_{n\to\infty} x_n = -1.
$$